# How to get WETH balance from a Metamask wallet

Tags: tokens

I need to find out how to find the WETH balance of a wallet that contains both ETH and WETH.
When trying to put a hold on a specific amount of WETH we need to know that the user actually has a sufficient balance of WETH.
Right now when reserving the amount Metamask opens asks for access to the WETH, charges an amount of ETH for gas and then tells me it's success.
The problem is it will do the same for a wallet that has no WETH and still tells me it was successful, so I need to manually confirm that the user has sufficient WETH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the return info could be success, also could be the exact amount. do you try this way to check the `balanceOf` the WETH?

```
async function getWETHBalance(address) {
  // Get the WETH contract instance
  const wethContract = new web3.eth.Contract(WETH_CONTRACT_ABI, WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

  // Call the balanceOf function of the WETH contract to get the balance of the given address
  const balance = await wethContract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();

  // Print the balance to the console
  console.log(balance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly for me